# Legend title position in

Tags: highcharts, legend

I'm using the legend title, but it's being positioned to the left and above the legend items:

[image]

While I need it to be to the right, and on the same line as, the legend items:

[image]

[Legend title](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.title) only accepts 2 properties - `title` and `style`,.

Using `style` - I couldn't find any style property to move it (tried `float`, `textAlign`).

Using `text` - I tried wrapping the title in HTML tag with `style="transform:translate(742,18);"`, but that doesn't do anything to it either.

From analyzing it in Firebug, I see that the item which I can control in the style isn't the actual item that's in charge of the positioning. The item I want to control is the one highlighted in blue, but the one I'm actually controlling is its inner item:

[image]

How can I position the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to control that title using `$(".highcharts-legend-title text")` ? Then set new `transform` attribute. But be careful with IE8 - it's using VML, not SVG.

Or in a Highcharts way:

```
var title = chart.legend.title;
title.translate(x, y); // translate legend's title
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rum1rcum/

Comment: Thank you very much. Fortunately, we don't need to support any version of IE.

Comment: Just to be on the same page, second solution works both, in VML and SVG.

Comment: Oh great, because the second solution is the one I ended up using.